# How can i change the selection of textfield copy paste options

Tags: swift, uitextfield

1)Take Input  from Text Field and Input will show on bottom of Text field and Input has multiple Words.

2)Long press on single world It will appear a toast with multiple option opy ,paste ,change color .

3)Click on change color option selected Word should be change color .

4)Click on double click It should be redirect with same words.

Comment: Check your spellings.  'single world'?  'option opy'?  'be change'?

Comment: sry it's typing mistake it's copy

Answer (score 0):

Add addition menu item using UIMenuController, something like this:

```
let changeColor = UIMenuItem(title: "Change Color", action: #selector(changeColor:))
UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [changeColor]
```

You can make the changes in `changeColor` function and update textfield's content from there with your color attributes.

Double-tap is used to show menu controller options, changing that may not be straight forward change. You need to explore swizzling to achieve that.

Comment: i don't about objective c can u tell me how can i achieve this in swift

Comment: updated with swift, you can explore more around `UIMenuController` and `UIMenu` for customization.